# Socialite Facebook Login via Restful API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I have Socialite working fine with Facebook login on website, but now I'm working to extend the project with an android app and I want to be able to support social login, (so users can use same credentials on android) trying to use this method:

```
Socialite::driver('facebook')->userFromToken($request->input("access_token")`
```

But now I'm running into an issue about an "appsecret". Which led me to realise Facebook required me to create a different "app" for my android app. So I would now have two different secrets.

So in summary, how do I make socialite work with two Facebook "Apps". Unless I'm overcomplicating it? Hoping I am.

Thanks!

Comment: No you should just use one app. And you should never include your app secret in your android app

Comment: @WizKid oh ok. I thought Facebook insisted having a different app for both my mistake thanks! Yea i'm not, keeping it server side, just meant that the response didn't match because different secret